# iterate a variable in an Angular JS repeater?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a setup where a div hides and shows the following div, to create a collapsing div.  I am using a variable to ng-show that div, and the div that does the hide/show is

`<div ng-click="costSummary=!costSummary" ng-class="{open : costSummary}">`

Clicking the div toggles the variable and the class (to style a header inside, for a disclosure triangle).  Works fine.

However, I need to use this construct in an ng-repeat, and I'm not sure how I can increment that variable so each iteration has a unique class.  As in:

`<div ng-click="myVar1=!myVar1" ng-class="{open : myVar1}" ng-repeat="claim in claims">`

since this hide/show requires each header/div pair to have a unique class name.

How can I append the index number or something in this case?

Comment: you could use a directive with an isolated scope

Comment: Have you tried a scope property with a dot?  Like `visible.costSummary`?  Since every `ng-repeat` has its own scope, this will make sure you are not overwriting the parent scope property.

Comment: $index is an option, or you can modify claims object so each claim has an open flag as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to add several variables in `ng-repeat`. because `ng-repeat` creates a child scopes in each and every repeat. so the variable creates with in the child scopes, so one variable not visible to the other child scopes in `ng-repeat`

so,

```
<div ng-click="myVar1=!myVar1" ng-class="{open : myVar1}" ng-repeat="claim in claims">
{{  claim }}
</div>
```

this would be enough.

here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Iw6yCLw7NyuJINcdHb6S?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks.  A couple of people have suggested almost the same thing.  I came up with this, btw: http://plnkr.co/edit/hz9PhTwtLwn8nOnS31PO?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Inside an ng-repeat, you have access to `$index` - which will give you the index of the current item in the collection you are iterating over. You could use that to generate unique class ids.

But, could you not also try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="claim in claims">
    <div ng-click="claim.myVar1=!claim.myVar1" ng-class="{open : claim.myVar1}">
    </div>
</div>
```

You place the div with ng-click inside an ng-repeater wrapper. Since you youse `claim in claims` you can set the variable on claim as you were doing before.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants *unique* class ids.  It is about a unique property to switch on.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But does he really need to get that unique property to switch on, or is that a bit jQuery like thinking and does he really want to have the object itself?

Comment: I was making the comment on your first sentence.  The rest I voted up :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to toggle visibility on a repeated div, you can do as such:

```
<div ng-click="claim.isOpen=!claim.isOpen" ng-class="{open : claim.isOpen}" ng-repeat="claim in claims" ng-init="claim.isOpen = false">
```

Explanation:

ng-init will initialize an "isOpen" variable on each repeated claim (This should really be done on the JS end instead). Then ng-click will toggle that isOpen variable. Then ng-class will watch for changes on that variable.

Comment: Thanks.  I originally didn't realize this.  I created a value in my JSON for it, not sure if even necessary.  See http://plnkr.co/edit/hz9PhTwtLwn8nOnS31PO?p=preview for finished item.